# Reflections of $d$ dimensional space

Tags: calculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $d=2$, and consider the region surrounded by $x=0$, $y=0$ and $x+y=1$, and call it $T_2$. Consider the square surrounded by $x=0$, $y=0$, $x=1$, $y=1$, and call it $C_2$. The volume of the region $T_2$ is $\dfrac{1}{2}$, and volume of $C_2$ is $1$. Consider this map $R_2: C_2 \rightarrow T_2$: for every point $p$ if  $p \in T_2$, then it returns $p$ itself. And if $p \notin T_2$, then it returns its reflection. The volume of $C_2$ is **two** times the volume of $T_2$. This map is a **two**-to-one map.

Let $d=3$, and consider the region surrounded by $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$ and $x+y+z=1$, and call it $T_3$. Consider the square surrounded by $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$, $x=1$, $y=1$, $z=1$ and call it $C_3$. The volume of the region $T_3$ is $\dfrac{1}{6}$, and volume of $C_3$ is $1$. The volume of $C_3$ is **six** times the volume of $T_3$. Is there a canonical map $R_3:C_3 \rightarrow T_3$, which is a **six**-to-one map?

Is there a canonical map $R_d: C_d \rightarrow T_d$, which is a **$D$**-to-one map, where $D$ is a number depending on $d$ (probably $D=d!$).

Comment: Is the volume of $T_3$ not $1/6$?

Comment: @OrangeMushroom I was mistaken, I will edit it

Comment: Long story short, no, you can't chop $C_3$ into six things looking like $T_3$. You can go with [orthoschemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_orthoscheme) (they will do in any dimension, too), but that's another story.

Comment: You may not be able to "chop" it, but you can still define some sort of nice enough map. You can split an $n$-cube into $n$ pyramids with an $(n-1)$-cube base. Then along each slice of the pyramid you use the map for the lower dimension. After identifying the copies you get, with some potentially non-canonical choices, everything is mapped to the simplex. Although, I guess there may be issues on the boundaries of such pyramids.